# Use dynamic type in place of TElement in DB Context C#

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, reflection

I created different store procedures and execute them through dbcontext and get results in respected viewmodels. I want to generalize this. I am doing like

```
switch (report.StoreProcedure)
{
    case "SP_BranchSaleReport":
        result = context.Database.SqlQuery<BranchReportVM>("dbo.SP_BranchSaleReport").ToList();
        return PartialView("~/Views/Auto/Reports/InnerPartials/SP_BranchSaleReport.cshtml", result);
}
```

I want to make TElement in context.Database.SqlQuery<**DYNAMICTYPE**> dynamic so that I avoid using switch. I was unable to do it through reflection. How can I generalize it and avoid writing number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static List<T> GetViewModelFromSp<T>(string ProcedureName, ApplicationDbContext context)
{
    List<T> returnedList = new List<T>();

   returnedList = context.Database.SqlQuery<T>(ProcedureName).ToList<T>();

    return returnedList;
}
```

Comment: GetViewModelFromSp<???> I have to choose type! while calling this function, problem is same, you make a wrapper on it. isn't? @MuhammadBashir